# How can I properly use localstorage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am making a variable that saves its value on multiple pages, and I am using localstorage to do this. The problem is that it doesn't save the variable, and also gives no errors.

What I have tried to do before posting this:
I searched up youtube tutorials on localstorage
I tried using this website https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-use-local-storage-with-javascript/
I searched it up here on stackoverflow

And I can't find an answer to this.

Variables.js file

```
var mode = "light";

localStorage.setItem('mode', '');

function draw(){
  
  if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == "#181818"){
    mode = "dark";
    console.log(mode);
  }
  
  if (document.body.style.backgroundColor == "#f2f112" || mode == "dark"){
    mode = "dark";
    alert("Error while attempting to change background to dark theme.")
  }


}
```

index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p><a href="settings.html">Settings</a></p>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="variables.js"></script>
    <script src="settings.html"></script>
    <script>

    modeselect = localStorage.getItem(mode);

    if (modeselect == "light"){
      console.log("light mode");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f2f112";
    }
    if (modeselect == "dark"){
      console.log("dark mode");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#f2f112";
    }

  </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

settings.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Settings</title>
  </head>
  <style>
  .button1 {
  background-color: #444444;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
  .button2 {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  }
  body {
    background-color: rgb(156,158,158);
  }
</style>

<body>
<form>
  <input type="button" class="button1" value="Dark mode" onclick="darkmode()">
  <input type="button" class="button2" value="Light mode" style ="color:black;" onclick="lightmode()">
</form>
<p><a href="index.html">Home</a></p>
<script src="variables.js"></script>
<script>
localStorage.getItem('mode');
function darkmode() {
  mode = "dark";
  alert(mode);
  if (mode == "light"){
    alert("error while changing theme");
  }
  if (mode == "dark"){
  alert("successfully changed to dark mode");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#181818";
  }
}
function lightmode() {
  mode = "light";
  alert(mode);
  if (mode == "light"){
    alert("successfully changed to light mode");
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#9c9e9e";
  }
  if (mode == "dark"){
    alert("error while changing theme");
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You's not set value in localstorage. Your set localstorage is value empty.

Use "localStorage.setItem" with value "mode". Example:

```
localStorage.setItem('mode', mode);
```

To get value use localStorage.getItem('mode')

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = localStorage.getItem('mode') || "gray";
function darkmode() {
    mode = 'black'
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = mode;
    localStorage.setItem('mode', mode);
}
function lightmode() {
    mode = 'white'
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = mode;
    localStorage.setItem('mode', mode);
}
```

```css
[type="button"] {
    border: none;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" style ="color:black;background-color: white;"  value="Light mode" onclick="lightmode()">
<input type="button" style ="color:white;background-color: black;" value="Dark mode" onclick="darkmode()">
```